# Trying to pause video when the UICollectionViewCell is out of view

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer

I'm populating a collection view with URLs loaded from Firebase. But I can't get the video to pause when I exit the view or scroll the collection view up. When I go back using the navigation controller, I can still hear the video playing in the background. Then when I enter the view again, the video starts playing, but the first one never finished.

This is my view controller. Any tips? thank you! I'm still new to Swift, so please excuse any ignorance on my end.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

class ComedyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    var avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var comedyCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var comedyVideoArray = [ComedyModel]()

    var comedyDBRef: DatabaseReference! {
        return Database.database().reference().child("comedy")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadComedyDB()
    }


    func loadComedyDB() {
        comedyDBRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.comedyVideoArray.removeAll()

                for comedyData in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let comedyObject = comedyData.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let comedyPostTitle = comedyObject?["title"]
                    let comedyPostDescription = comedyObject?["description"]
                    let comedyArticleLink = comedyObject?["link"]
                    let comedyVideoUrl = comedyObject?["url"]
                    let allComedyData = ComedyModel(title: comedyPostTitle as! String?, description: comedyPostDescription as! String?, link: comedyArticleLink as! String?, url: comedyVideoUrl as! String?)

                    self.comedyVideoArray.append(allComedyData)

                    self.comedyCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(comedyVideoArray.count)
        return comedyVideoArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cellB = comedyCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "comedyCell", for: indexPath) as! ComedyCollectionViewCell
        let data = comedyVideoArray[indexPath.row]
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: data.url!)!)

        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

        self.avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.avPlayer)
        self.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellB.frame.size.width, height: cellB.frame.size.height / 2)

        cellB.videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer)

        self.avPlayer.play()
        //cellB.videoView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: data.link!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "1"))

        return cellB
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == self.comedyCollectionView {
            self.avPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There're several issues:

1. `UICollectionView` calls `cellForItemAt` before it shows new cell which means that old cell is still visible. Now, when you dequeue new cell, you are changing your pointer `avPlayer` to the new instance of `AVPlayer` so that when you're pausing the video you're actually calling `pause()` on a new video. The old one continues to play (in a cell that is still visible at the time).
2. You're adding an instance of `AVPlayer` to the cell each time `UICollectionView` calls `cellForItemAt`. But `UICollectionView` tries to reuse those cells which are no longer visible so you can end up with a lot of `AVPlayer`s in each cell. To avoid that you should check out how to use `prepareForReuse` method on cells. I also suggest you to create `AVPlayer` in cell itself (by subclassing the `UICollectionViewCell`) and then set its `playerItem` in `cellForItemAt` method. This way you could pause currently playing video in your `didEndDisplaying` method like this (just an example):

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if let comedyCell = cell as? ComedyCollectionViewCell {
       comedyCell.avPlayer.pause()
     } 
   }
   ```

Comment: you sir saved my life

Comment: Note to self. Don't build apps for the mafia.

Comment: @Dan Karbayev Hello, Sir, I've created AVPlayers in the cell, and I'm pausing it in the prepareForReuse, but it's still playing,Hope you can answer, thank you very much

Comment: how to resume when he comes back ?